# Compound Interest Calculator - C

Tags: c, printf, scanf

The output is totally wrong, I expected it to print one line, then scan my input into the variable, then print the next line, scan my input, etc etc. But it prints the first line, then I have to put my number twice for it to do anything, and it's just downhill from there. Any help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    float balance;
    int years;
    float interestRateAnual;
    int frequencyOfInterest;
    double totalCost;

    printf( "Insert amount of money to be deposited.\n" );
    scanf( "%f\n", &balance );

    printf( "How many years for the interest?\n" );
    scanf( "%d\n", &years );

    printf( "What is the anual interest rate?\n" );
    scanf( "%f\n", &interestRateAnual );

    printf( "How many times per year is the interest compounded?\n" );
    scanf( "%d\n", &frequencyOfInterest );

    totalCost = pow(balance*(1 + interestRateAnual/frequencyOfInterest), years);

    printf( "After %d years, with an interest rate of %f% per year, ", years, interestRateAnual );
    printf( "the total you will have to pay is %e.\n", totalCost );


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)  
{   
float balance;   
int years;  
float interestRateAnual;  
int frequencyOfInterest;  
double totalCost; 

printf( "Insert amount of money to be deposited.\n" );
scanf( "%f\n", &balance );

printf( "How many years for the interest?\n" );
scanf( "%d\n", &years );

printf( "What is the anual interest rate?\n" );
scanf( "%f\n", &interestRateAnual );

printf( "How many times per year is the interest compounded?\n" );
scanf( "%d\n", &frequencyOfInterest );

totalCost = balance*pow((1 + interestRateAnual/frequencyOfInterest), (years*frequencyOfInterest));

printf( "After %d years, with an interest rate of %f% per year, ", years, interestRateAnual );
printf( "the total you will have to pay is %e.\n", totalCost );


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please remove the `\n` from **all** the `scanf()`:

1. Replace `scanf( "%d\n", &years );` with `scanf( "%d", &years );`
2. Replace `scanf( "%f\n", &balance );` with  `scanf( "%f\n", &balance );`

and so on...

The '\n' character is still left on the input stream after the first call to scanf is completed, so the second call to scanf() reads it in.

If you look at a reference for [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) you will see that:

> The format string consists of whitespace characters (any single
>   whitespace character in the format string consumes all available
>   consecutive whitespace characters from the input)

So the \n will trigger this effect, if you don't want this behavior just leave out the \n:

scanf("%d", &years);

Alternatively, you can use the following function:

```
void fflushstdin( void )
{
    int c;
    while( (c = fgetc( stdin )) != EOF && c != '\n' );
}
```

to clear out your input buffer.

Comment: Just adding additional info instead of another answer, when you include a `\n` in the format argument of scanf in your case `"%f\n"` what you are telling it to do is basically read a float number, and then reads any whitespace or newline characters it finds, until it finds a non-whitespace character.